# derby sql difference between two aggregate values or how to combine two sql statements

Tags: sql, derby

The following two queries work by themselves:

```
select coalesce(sum(shares*cps),0.0)  from 
transactions
where usr = 1
and (type = 'C'
or type  = 'S')

select coalesce(sum(shares*cps),0.0) from 
transactions
where usr = 1
and (type = 'W'
or type  = 'B')
```

How do I combine them to get the difference between them?  Something like:

```
select coalesce(sum(a.shares*a.cps),0.0) - coalesce(sum(b.shares*b.cps),0.0)   from 
      (select * from transactions
                where usr = 1
                  and (type = 'C'
                   or type  = 'S')) as a,
      (select * from transactions
                where usr = 1
                  and (type = 'W'
                   or type  = 'B')) as b;
```

value returned is 0. the first coalesce returns 200000.00 and the second coalesce returns 0.00

Comment: Side note: I think you'll want parens around your ORs `...where usr = 1 and (type = 'C' or type = 'S')...where usr = 1 and (type = 'W' or type = 'B')`

Comment: In your individual queries you coalesce with `0.0`. In your combined query you coalesce with `0`. Perhaps an implicit conversion issue?

Comment: no difference between 0 and 0.0 in the coalesce function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SYSDUMMY1`, a dummy table with one record that can be used to select simple values, in this case the difference between the two sums:

```
select 
( select coalesce(sum(shares*cps),0.0)  from 
  transactions
  where usr = 1
  and (type = 'C'
       or type  = 'S')) -
( select coalesce(sum(shares*cps),0.0) from 
  transactions
  where usr = 1
  and (type = 'W'
       or type  = 'B')) as DIFFERENCE
from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: that seems to work.  can you provide an explanation?

Comment: Yes. So `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` returns a single row. Instead of using the column from that table, you can also return a fixed or calculated value, for instance `select 5-3 from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` (returns 2). Instead of 5 and 3, I subtract the results from the other queries. That is possible because each of them will return exactly one value.